# OutOfMemoryError when try to store big data in SharedPreferences, Android

Tags: android, gson, android-sharedpreferences

**Problem:** I want to store huge Map of objects (1000 contacts) into SharedPreferences.

I have Cordova application where 1st time a load all contacts and convert all photos to base64 String.

Generally this process might take about 30 sec. For that reason my goal to store all contacts as String to SharedPreferences to load after quickly.

I use GSON library but no matter what I do, I get:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:354)
       at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:171)
       at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toString(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:137)
```

This is my method where I convert my Map to `ByteArrayOutputStream` but get Exception in last line: `out.toString()`

---

```
public static String getStrFromGroupsListJSONObject(ConcurrentHashMap<String, WmContactImage> contactMap){

        Gson gson = getInstance();  
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));

            Iterator<String> it = contactMap.keySet().iterator();

            WmContactImage img;

            writer.beginObject(); // {


            while(it.hasNext()){
                String key = it.next();

                writer.name(key);

                img = contactMap.get(key);

                gson.toJson(img, WmContactImage.class, writer);
            }           

            writer.endObject();   // }
            writer.close();             
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out.toString();
    }
```

Is there any other way to store Map in SharedPreferences or can I somehow store `OutputStream`?

Comment: "I want to store huge Map of objects (1000 contacts) into SharePreferences" -- why? If this is in JSON, use a JSON file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't have JSON. I try to create one. If I'll convert my MAP to JSON string , I get `OutOfMemoryError` . So I used `JsonWriter`. but still get the same exception when try to get String from `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Thanks,

Comment: @CommonsWare the only way that might work is to split map to several parts and save one by one

Answer (score 1):

Use a file http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html . the shared preferences are not supposed to store big data. Use a file or sqlote database.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are not the way to go if you want to store huge amounts of data. You should probably use a SQLite Database on the device. You can read in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) how to do that exactly

Comment: I know but I actually need `SELECT *` only. As I know SQLite is slower then SharePreferences and its good to use when you want to run some queries with conditions

Comment: @fessy `As I know SQLite is slower then SharePreferences` - how do you know?  Have you measured it?  TmKVU is right.  SharedPreferences is not the way to go.  If you don't want SQLite (which for 1000 contacts would be very fast), then store the JSON file.

Comment: @Simon While it is true that searching for specific keys may be slow, this won't affect your performance. Since you will be requesting the whole dataset there is no searching involved and you are practically requesting the whole file in a convenient way.